# Open a Image File into a Picturebox making it a Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox, openfiledialog

I want to be able to open either a .jpg, .gif or .bmp into a picturebox and make it a bitmap so i can draw on it, but at the moment it comes up with an error of 'Parameter is not valid' when i run my program and then try to load one of these image files into my picturebox.
This is my current code:

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"N:\My Documents\My Pictures";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG Compressed Image (*.jpg|*.jpg" + "|GIF Image(*.gif|*.gif" + "|Bitmap Image(*.bmp|*.bmp";
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;         
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    capturebox.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ofd2.FileName);
}
```

I don't know why this occurs, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us where the error occurs?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding things correctly but in your code snippet the user is selecting a file from openFileDialog1 but you are using the filename from ofd2. How is the filename of ofd2 populated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to replace `ofd2` with `openFileDialog1` on the penultimate line.